# check if text Widget has style

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a default style to a `Text` `Widget`, but I need to be able to overwrite it.

this is what I am trying right now.

```
var newTitle = title;
    if (title is Text) {
      Text titleText = title as Text;
      newTitle = Text(titleText.data, style: TextStyle == null ? TextStyle() : TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
    }
```

So I want to check if it has style if not add the default style to it, otherwise use overwriten

Comment: yes, I want to check if the child Widget of Text() I've added has style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter provides a simple way to do this by providing a `DefaultTextStyle` widget, which can be used to specify a default texty style for the subtree. If a child `Text` widget already defines a style, the specific Text style will be used.

```dart
DefaultTextStyle(
  child: title,
  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
),
```